# serial buffer communication 8051 with nfc

Tags: serial-port, microcontroller, keil, 8051

I have problems with serial communications microcontroler 8051. My hardware MCU with att7035au and module-1350M CJH NFC reader. I have tested the pc and mcu to receive and transmit with usb-ttl / rs232 goes well. for sending 1 character and length data successfully without error. But after I try communication between mcu with NFC module there is an error during the receive data from the NFC. I use an interrupt to receive the data.

example :
mcu send (hex data):

```
02 55 00 03 03 E0 B7
```

NFC receiving data mcu and send feedback:

```
02 55 00 02 FF AA
```

mcu receive the data from NFC should (`02 55 00 02 FF AA`) but received

```
02 55 00 02 FF 05
```

What is wrong?why MCU read receive data error.

my code config:

```
BWPR = 0xcf;
BWPR = 0xbc;
PLLCFG = 0x87;  
CLKCFG |= 0x04;
EA = 1;     
//Serial config 0   
SCON0 = 0x50 ;                  //SCON: serail mode 1, 8-bit UART
PCON|=0x80;                     //PCON.7 (SMOD)  Indicate  Baud rate double 
SMOD_1=1;                       //ADCON.7 
S0RELL=0xfd;                    //115200bps
S0RELH=0x03;
TI=0;
RI=0;
ES0 = 1 ;
```

edit add code interrupt:

```
void    UART_0(void)    interrupt   4
{
    if(SCON0&0x01){     //RI=1
        SCON0=SCON0&0xfc;       //RI=0
        card_id[RECE_NUMB]=SBUF0;
        if(RECE_NUMB==6){
            if(card_id[1]==0x02&&card_id[2]==0x55&&card_id[5]==0xff){
                f_ReceiveSucceed=1;
                SCON0&=0xef;                 //disable receive
            }
        }
        ++RECE_NUMB; 
    }
    SCON0=0x50;      
}
```

for code main(void):

```
while(1)
{ 
//...
//lines of code to send NFC
//...

if(f_ReceiveSucceed)
    {
        f_ReceiveSucceed=0;
        SerialCommunication();                      
    }           
}
```

if get receive so i send to serialcommunication() for monitor data serial with usb-ttl

```
void SerialCommunication(void){
    unsigned char count;
    ES0 = 0;
    for(count=0;count<=50;count++)
    { 
        SBUF0=card_id[count];
        while(TI==0);
        TI=0;
    }
    ES0 = 1;
    clear();
    SCON0=0x50;  //open receive

}

void clear(void)
{
    unsigned char r;
    for(r=0;r<50;r++){
        card_id[r]=0x00;
    }
    RECE_NUMB=0;
}
```

Comment: Are you using a serial receive buffer and how long is it? Probably need to see your serial interrupt routine and the code processing the characters to provide more diagnostics.

Comment: Thanks @jeff , I use a very long buffer ex: I send data char A to Z is not a problem between MCU with PC (with usb-ttl/rs-232) but when using the NFC reader there is a data error. I am adding line code you can see it

Comment: In the SerialCommuncation routine you start your serial buffer at 0, however I noticed in your UART_0 interrupt routine you test for card_id[1]==0x02, I would expect that character to be in card_id[0] . I don't know if this is related to your error or not.

Comment: I have found problem on config interrupt priority because I set interrupt others too. thanks your help